# rufus scheduler first day months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

I  try to execute a cron every first day of the month.

I see how do on every first monday but no on first day.

```
scheduler.cron('00 12 * * mon#1') do
     # ...
end
```

I try with:

```
scheduler.cron('00 12 * * #1') do
  # ...
end
```

how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is:

```
┌───────────── min (0 - 59)
│ ┌────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│ │ ┌─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│ │ │ ┌──────────────── month (1 - 12)
│ │ │ │ ┌───────────────── day of week (0 - 6)
│ │ │ │ │
* * * * *

"0 12 1 * *"
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Configuration_file